# Best soldering iron for electronics projects

Tags: soldering

I was working with someone today trying to build a radio receiver and transceiver. First we went to build the coil needed and as it turns out the soldering iron we had bit the dust. So we went to use a soldering gun went also was ruined. I was told that I may need a 100-150watt soldering gun as opposed to a soldering iron for projects. What is better for electronics jobs? Like working with arduinos, breadboards or maybe car projects? what wattage should it be? I am not familiar with this. I was going to get a weller 40watt soldering iron but heard I should get a soldering gun around 100-150watt.

Just want some second opinions here on what you all think is best.

Thank you

Comment: Primarily opinion based perhaps, but Metcal is certainly one of the best. Probably out of the reach cost-wise of casual hobbyists.

Comment: There is a best and it is Metcal :)  Long live the foo.

Comment: The best is obviously the one that served me for decades. It has build up tremendeously amounts of good karma.

Answer (score 3):

Get a soldering iron with temperature control. 30-60W is OK, personally I prefer the higher end of that range.

A soldering gun is fine for occasionally soldering on a wire-frame art project. Don't let it get near electronics.

A 100-150 Watt soldering iron is nice for soldering big electron tube sockets. I guess that is not what you intend to do.

Answer (score 2):

Weller is definitely a good brand as well as Hakko.
40W should be perfect for the applications you have described, just make sure you can control the temperature. 100-150W guns are usually used for plastic welding, very heavy gauge wires, and plumbing.
When you buy tips make sure you do not only buy the fine tipped ones. A screwdriver tip is a must have since it is so versatile.
Finer soldering wire gives you more control when you solder circuits, but thicker soldering wire is nice for soldering wires.
Dave Jones (EEVBlog on Youtube) has some very nice soldering tutorials that I would recommend checking out.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is no "best", it all depends on the job at hand.

For example, you wouldn't use a 150 watt gun to hand-solder 0.5mm lead pitch integrated circuits, nor would you use a 10 watt pencil to solder shield braid directly to copper-clad FR-4.

Comment: No best - but Metcal try very hard. If you have never seen how they work specifically have a look. Very ingenious. RF delivered to the tip "on demand".

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: Nice tools... Over the last 20 years or so I've used Weller WTCPT power supplies with TC201 hand tools and EC234 heaters for everything from soldering grounds directly to chassis to 1/2 millimeter lead pitch SMT packages. So far, no problems except for the eyes as time goes by. :-(